# DeselectAll doesn't work for Bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

Here is example what i try, but didn't work.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/10/)

What i expect : on button click all options will be unselected.

I try with "refresh" and "render" but also didn't help.

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Not changable text" data-count-selected-text="Not changable text">
         <option>Mustard</option>
         <option>Ketchup</option>
         <option>Relish</option>
 </select>

<button id="f1">ggg</button>

$('#f1').click(function(){
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
});
```

---

UPDATE : code doesn't work if select is closed. In case it's open - all is good

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### EDIT

There was a bug with `deselectAll` and [**is now fixed**](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/pull/926)

---

You can empty selection using [`val`](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#methods) :

```
$('#f1').click(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '');
});
```

<s>`DeselectAll` should theoretically do the job, but for some reason it doesn't.</s> (it does now)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/re8tevoc/11/)

Comment: In my experience 'deselectAll' only works when the dropdown is opened, this answer works for both open and closed. Thanks

Comment: Downvoter, please share the reason so I can improve my answer

Comment: DeselectAll still not working for me (selectpicker v 1.13.8) your solution work well thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got solution from following code.Try it

```
$("#listID").val('').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

```
$('.selectpicker option:selected').val('');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **Artur Filipiak** answer,

If it does not work for you, add this :

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

after you add :

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '');
```

it should look something like this :

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reset my non-multi selectpicker to the noneSelectedText with the following. It even works if you change the noneSelectedText.

`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 'Nothing Selected').selectpicker("refresh");`